# Solving Subset Sum Without the Use of Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, pseudo-polynomial, subset-sum

I am looking for algorithmic techniques to solve the Subset Sum Problem in pseudopolynomial time. There is, of course, a textbook dynamic programming approach for Subset Sum. Have any other algorithmic techniques (Randomized, Linear Programming...) been successfully applied to this problem?

In [1], the authors state that "[T]the only algorithm known to solve subset sum (in time polynomial in the numbers involved) is dynamic programming" (page 3). This paper, however, is 8 years old and it might be possible that some progress has been made in the recent past.

[1] Reid Andersen, and Uriel Feige. Interchanging distance and capacity in
probabilistic mappings. Available at https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3631v1

Comment: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dakane/subsetsum.pdf ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Perhaps you would like to convert this to a full-fledged answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

[This paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dakane/subsetsum.pdf) has applied polynomial arithmetic to that problem.